# Remove entries from list of a generic list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model class like this

```
    public class InterestList
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Interest> interests { get; set; }
}
public class Interest
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int sortOrder { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public string categoryId { get; set; }
}
```

And an object `private List<InterestList> _interestlist;` which holds my data.

as you can see `_interestlist` contains a `list` of  `Interest` named `interests`  now i want to remove a single entry of it. How can I achieve this with Linq?

I have tried like

```
   _interestlist.RemoveAll(x => x.id == "1234");
```

but it removes `interests` only not `Interest`. Can any one point out the right way?

Comment: _interestlist.Interest.RemoveAll(x => x.id == "1234"); ?

Comment: _interestlist.ForEach(i => i.interests.RemoveAll(x => x.id == "1234"));

Comment: Which `id` are you refering to in your approach? Both classes have an ID property, which one with ID=1234 do you want to delete?

Comment: @wonko79: `_interestlist` is a single object, not an IEnumerable (one of its properties, however, is an IEnumerable). If I read it correctly, that is.

Comment: @Flater Solution by wonko79 is correct (except it should be ForEach). OP has `List<InterestList> _interestlist`.

Comment: @wonko79 Yours is correct answer please add it as answer here

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: I stand corrected. However, I also claim non-guilt for the mistake, as the naming used here is quite confusing ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
_interestlist.ForEach(i => i.interests.RemoveAll(x => x.id == "1234"));
```

will delete all objects in the interests lists contained in any of your InterestList objects in _interestlist with id = "1234".

Answer (score 7):

Technically you have a lists of lists, almost as if you had `List<List<Interest>>`. To solve this problem you will need to `foreach` over your collection and perform the `Remove` operation on the inner list.

```
foreach(InterestList interestList in _interestlist)
{
    interestList.interests.RemoveAll(x => x.id == "1234");
}
```

You also could use the `ForEach` method built in to `List<T>`

```
_interestlist.Foreach(i => i.interests.RemoveAll(x => x.id == "1234"));
```